# Dealing with 'const' objects requiring multiple lines to initialize

Tags: c++

This is a pretty basic question; sorry if it is very common but I can't find a specific answer.

Often I find myself in a situation where an object is inherently constant, but requires multiple lines to initialize. For example say I want a stride to be the product of an unknown-at-compile-time number of elements in a vector:

```
const std::vector<int> extentsVector; //pretend this is initialized
int stride = 1;
for (int i=0; i<k; ++i){
    stride *= extentsVector[i];
}
```

Anyway, you get the idea. I never want to touch 'stride' again so it should be const. What's the preferred way to deal with this? Do I use a temporary to compute the value and then assign it to a 'const' object? Or is a const-cast better? Or do I just leave it non-const?

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Do not add unrelated tags.

Comment: @Olaf Aside from the 'std::vector' in the example (which is not fundamental to the actual question) I feel the basic idea of this question is equally applicable to both languages, but OK no problem.

Comment: A proper solution might be very different, depending on language. Just don't use C tag for C++ and vice versa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an initializer function:

```
int ComputeStride() {
    int s = 1;
    for (auto e: extentsvector)
        s *= e;
    return s;
}
const int stride = ComputeStride();
```

Comment: How would that be called for a `const` object which might be located in read-only memory?

Comment: @Olaf I don't think the compiler will place complex data structures in read-only memory, mainly because it probably can't initialize them at compile time.

Comment: @immibis: As always there is no simple answer to this. Bascially: it depends. If all elements are `const`, there should be little to no problem (yes, that might also be oversimplified). Otherwise e.g. embedded systems might run into massive trouble with RAM-usage.

Comment: @Olaf: In C++ language class constructors and destructors are guaranteed to see their objects as *modifiable*, regardless of whether these objects are `const` or not (excluding `constexpr`, probably) . How the compilers are going to implement that with "read-only memory" is their problem. Most likely, they will never place non-trivial objects into read-only memory. Where did you even get that idea?

Comment: @AnT: OP asked about initialising a `const` object, which does not necessarily mandate a constructor, but might also be a C-like `struct`, but with different initialiser syntax. As I wrote above, there is no simple answer. I did not say the constructor above will work with such an object. Actually I questioned that quite clearly. (btw: can an object with constructor be `const` actually? Wouldn't that contradict the sense of `const`?)

Answer (score 4):

Common way to do this in c++11 is to use a lambda function to intialize the const variable:

```
const std::vector<int> extentsVector;
const int stride = [&extentsVector] () -> int
{
    int stride = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        stride *= extentsVector[i];
    }
    return stride;
}();
```